# php code to change background colour based on date

Tags: php, sql, date, background

Hi I have this code which should change the background colour if the date is 2 months near expiry but for some reason it doesn't work properly. I think it only changes if the year is smaller not the actual date. Any help is appreciated.
my code is:

```
    $expires  = date("Y/m/d",(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+2, date("d"), date("Y"))));
    echo ($expires."<br>");
    $dateDue = date('m/d/Y');

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblitemdates ORDER BY name ");

    $result->execute();

    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

?>

<tr class="record">
<?php


if ($row["dateDue"] == NULL)
echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($row["dateDue"]< $expires)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';
else if ($row["st1"] == NULL)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($row["st1"]< $expires)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';

  else
  echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">'; ?>
```

regards,
B

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, I find its always better to compare unix timestamps as its a much easier format to work with in terms of comparing dates to each other.

you can get this with your expires variable as follows...

```
$expires  = date("Y/m/d",(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+2, date("d"), date("Y"))));
$expiresUnix = strtotime($expires); // This should give you the unix timestamp of your formatted date.

[ RUN DB FETCH CODE ]

$dateDueUnix = strtotime($row['dateDue']);
$st1Unix = strtotime($row['st1']);
```

and then in your if else...

```
<?php
if ($dateDueUnix == NULL)
echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($dateDueUnix< $expiresUnix)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';
else if ($st1Unix == NULL)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($st1Unix < $expiresUnix)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';

  else
  echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">'; ?>
```

Note you may need to change the == NULL to == 0 as I'm not too sure if $st1Unix will do the conversion if no argument is supplied. Hope this gets you somewhere

Comment: Wow, this was quick and it works. Thanks a lot Duenna.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the extra `<tr class="record">`

```
$expires  = date("Y/m/d",(mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")+2, date("d"), date("Y"))));
    echo ($expires."<br>");
    $dateDue = date('m/d/Y');

    $result = $db->prepare("SELECT * FROM tblitemdates ORDER BY name ");

    $result->execute();

    for($i=0; $row = $result->fetch(); $i++){

?>

<?php
if ($row["dateDue"] == NULL)
echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($row["dateDue"]< $expires)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';
else if ($row["st1"] == NULL)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">';
else if ($row["st1"]< $expires)
    echo '<tr style="background-color:#FFCC99">';

  else
  echo '<tr style="background-color:#ffffff">'; ?>
```